# Region of interest extraction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, foreground, roi

I am writing a MATLAB code to implement a specific filter on a selected (from auto ROI) grayscale region of a forearm image which consists of veins. I also uploaded the forearm of a subject (after foreground has extracted).

Basically, I have NIR camera images of the forearm of different subjects with different orientations. I wrote the code that has extracted the foreground grayscale image of the arm, that gave me the white background with the forearm. I used Sobel edge to find edges. I also found the nonzero indices using the `find` function. I got the row and col indices. I need an idea on how to extract image inside (almost 10 pixels) of the edges detected on both sides of the forearm (black and white edged image-also uploaded).

**Sobel-edge:**

[image: sobel-edge]

**Foreground image:**

[image: Foreground image]

**ROI image that I need to extract:**

[image: roi image that I need to extract]

```
clear all
close all
clc

image= rgb2gray(imread('Subj1.jpg'));
image1=~im2bw(image,0.1);
image1=im2uint8(image1);
foreground=imadd(image1,image);
imshow(foreground);
edgesmooth=medfilt2(foreground);
sobeledge= edge(edgesmooth,'sobel');
sobeledge=im2uint8(sobeledge);
figure 

imshow(sobeledge);
[col,row]=find(sobeledge~=0);
```

Comment: You want us to make an entire project in an answer of SO? Maybe with a couple of month, if you hire 4 or 5 of us

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Extract 10 pixels inside seems to me like an `imdillate` on the black and white image.  https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html

Comment: Why do people always use the Sobel edge detector? What is wrong with just thresholding this image to get the arm?

Comment: @CrisLuengo lmao

Comment: I don't even understand what you actually want to achieve

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Your point is valid based on the way I asked this question. Actually, I used Sobel operator to get the sharp transition region (boundary) of the forearm and then based on the points/indices of those pixels (I mentioned I used 'find' to do so) I need to used control loop statement to get an image with 10 pixels inside of the actual image. I am uploading an image file, of the final result, There are ways to do it manually like using 'roipoly' function, but I need to do it automatically. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @AnderBiguri I am extracting a region of the forearm to avoid sharp transition of background and foreground. I apologize if I was not clear before. Can you help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a much clearer and sensical question now. I have reversed my vote. Look for `imdilate`. You want to apply that to the mask of the forearm to extend it by a certain distance. Use a disk structuring element. If I have time today I'll write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the mask image that you make here:

```
image1=~im2bw(image,0.1);
```

but inverted, such that the mask is zero for the background and non-zero for the foreground:

```
image1 = im2bw(image,0.1);
```

you can use [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) to expand it by a fixed distance:

```
se = strel('disk',20); % This will extend by 20/2=10 pixels
image2 = imdilate(image1,se);
```

`image2` will be like `image1`, but expanded by 10 pixels in all directions.

`imerode` does the opposite, it shrinks regions.